# How to copy/edit a table of data directly into a single listbox in an Excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I want to create a userform where information like chemical composition can be edited directly in the userform OR pasted from another Excel sheet into the cells of the userform. Using textboxes is the best solution I have come up with so far, but this would not allow me to paste data from another Excel sheet or to cut or expand the number of inputs to match the number of chemical components in the system (which is variable).

I am still thinking that there is a solution where I can use a listbox, but I have not found a way to do this such that the entries in the listbox can be edited. I can use the listbox to show the chemical components and their composition, but I don't know how I can let the user edit the entries in the listbox.

Comment: You can't edit listbox entries, it's a *listbox*, not a *gridview*.

Comment: That said if you need a "grid UI", why not use a... worksheet for that?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I am using a worksheet for this now, but this means that I have to navigate the user to another worksheet and then navigate back to the original sheet. This is simple to do, but the userform would be a more elegant solution.

Comment: You could arrange the windows such that everything that needs to be in sight, is in sight. A UserForm is only an elegant solution if it involves elegant code... and there's no way you'll get anything grid-like on a UserForm without cursing ;-)  ...have you considered an Access solution? Another way (with deployment issues, maybe) could be to make the UI in .NET / WinForms (has a nice gridview control), and load it in VBA - although, getting a .NET UI to talk to VBA gracefully requires a rather solid understanding of OOP and UI design patterns.